# Return values from another tab if one value matches and another meets criteria

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, substitution

I am trying to match the value of column A on the first tab and return the scores for each condition in the correct columns. I tried VLOOKUP with the fuction below but could not figure out how to return the conditions in the correct column.

Here is the formula i tried.

```
=VLOOKUP(A3, Data!A2:C20,3,false)
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17ixnSMdgYNme_lxJNoMo8b4xf09oPX24LCV1x_dQ7_Y/edit#gid=621957136

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**plain text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to the question. Adding such "markdown tables" greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&SUBSTITUTE(B1:D1, " Score", ), 
 {Data!A:A&Data!B:B, Data!C:C}, 2, )))
```

[image]